# Let $V = C([a,b])$ be the vector space consisting of all functions $f(t)$ which are defined and continuous on the interval $ 0 \leq t \leq 1.$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is $f(0) = 2f(1)$ a subspace of V?

I'm a bit confused on this problem,

if I can show that $c_1f(0) + c_2g(0) = 2c_1f(1) + 2c_2g(2)$ then I've shown that $f(0) = 2f(1)$ is a vector space?

So If I write,

$c_1f(0) + c_2g(0) - 2c_1f(1) - 2c_2g(2) = 0$

and let $c_1 = c_2 = 0$ then have I shown that $f(0) = 2f(1)$ is a subspace of V?

Comment: You need to show precisely the  following : given two functions $f,g$ such that $f(0)=2f(1)$ and $g(0)=2g(1)$, that for all scalars $c,d$, $cf(0)+dg(0) = 2cf(1) + 2dg(1)$. This is easy to show, and your space is a subspace.

Answer (score 2):

No, $f(0)=2f(1)$ is not a subspace, it is an **equation**.

---

However, what you probably want to ask is whether $$X=\{f\in V| f(0)=2f(1)\}$$ is a subspace, and to answer that, you need to look at two things:

1. You have to prove (or disprove) that if $f$ is an element of $X$ and $\alpha$ is a real number, then $\alpha \cdot f$ is also an element of $X$.
2. You have to prove (or disprove) that if $f$ and $g$ are elements of $X$, then $f+g$ is also an element of $X$.

---

Now, how do you go about proving this?

Let's look at the first point. So, you have $f\in X$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb R$. Well, sinc $f\in X$, you know that $f(0)=2f(1)$. Now, what do you want to prove?

Well, you want to prove that $\alpha f\in X$. But you already know that

1. $\alpha f$ will be in $X$ if and only if $(\alpha f)(0)=2\cdot ((\alpha f)(0))$
2. By definition, for any $x$, $(\alpha f)(x) = \alpha\cdot f(x)$.

Now, it shouldn't be hard to merge the two pieces of information and prove that $\alpha f\in X$, I hope.

The second proof should be just as easy.

Comment: I think it was very important to point out the first statement. Thank you for that.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Sloppy writing just bugs me in all the wrong places :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You have to prove that, given two function $f,g \in C$ such that
$$
f(0)=2f(1) \quad \mbox{and} \quad g(0)=2g(1)
$$

than we have:
$$
(f+\alpha g)(0)=2[(f+\alpha g)(1)]
$$
(one multiplication  for a scalar $\alpha$ is sufficient). Can you do this?